# Подключение скрипта в head-е

Tags: javascript, jquery

Изучаю jQuery как и js не долго, хотелось бы узнать, чтобы  скрипт в шапке работал (и чтобы его не перемещать куда то в `footer`, допустим)нужно использовать

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

});
```

И получается,чтобы страница видела скрипт мне нужно писать весь `js` код между `{ }` или есть какие то другие способы? А если таких скриптов много будет, то что делать?

Comment: Тот скрипт который вы дали - функция.
Если вы хотите динамики на сайте,без функций не обойтись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
   // ваш код
});
```

Код сработает тогда когда DOM будет полностью загружен

Советую почитать https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

скрипты желательно подключать перед закрывающим тегом body.